# MongoDB Java driver - Object types

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb

I need to use the MongoDB Java drive since I need to use the driver within Matlab.

At the moment I have the followed problem. I get my BSON object from database, now I need to convert the BSON tree into a Matlab structure. My problem is that the BSONObject or BasisBSONObject class does not have a function to retrieve the type of the particluar BSON object (ARRAY, OBJECTID, ...). There is a class named BSON in the java driver that defines the values I need. But I do not know how to find out what type my current BSON object is.

The C++ driver and also the C# driver has a function that returns the type of a particular BSON element, but where is it in the JAVA driver.

Any advices are welcome. I'm not oerfect in JAVA maybe I did not find it for this reason...?

Comment: I don't think it has a type like that. The values in the BSONObject have types (you can retrieve them by `get(String)`), but not the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the object and call `getClass()` on it? `myBSON.get("myKey").getClass()` Seems like that is just as easy as calling some `myBSON.getTypeOf("myKey")` method that does not exist and would also be redundant in the API.

Comment: Thanks John, the solution is a kind of "strange" in comparsion to C++ and C# MongoDB driver but at all getClass() works for me to find out if my BSON element is a "value", "array" , ...

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use BSON<->Java POJO mapping libraries like Morphia or Spring-Data-Mongo.  These libraries have converters that can convert to and from mongo objects to type-safe objects.

Additionally, I think the Mongo 3.x driver is suppose to have better support for this.